# HTML5 Header Element Has Additional Space

Tags: css, html

I am having problems formatting an HTML5 `<header>` element with CSS. It seems no matter what I do, the header always renders several pixels larger in the height dimension than the `<img>` elements it contains.

The images are all equal height. In my CSS, I have a CSS Reset of padding and margins to 0, and no margins or padding assigned to either my images or my header. Rendering the page on my Mac with the Safari Browser, and in Chrome on an Android smartphone both render the header such that the images are all aligned at the top of the document within the header, but the header is always extending below the content by several pixels, almost like padding-bottom has been set to some value.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <img id="logo" src="images/csi_logo.svg" alt="csi logo">
    <img id="focus" src="images/home_icon.svg" alt="focus">
    <img id="hamburger" src="images/hamburger_icon.svg" alt="hamburger">
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 5vh;
}
header {
  background-color: #444444;
}
#logo {
  height: 10vh;
}
#focus {
  height: 10vh;
}
#hamburger {
  height: 10vh;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the nature of the `<img />` tag to align to `baseline`. Give:

```
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
```

for all the images and it should be alright.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 5vh;
}
header {
  background-color: #444444;
}
#logo {
  height: 10vh;
}
#focus {
  height: 10vh;
}
#hamburger {
  height: 10vh;
  float: right;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="logo" src="//placehold.it/300x75?text=csi_logo.svg" alt="csi logo" />
  <img id="focus" src="//placehold.it/300x75?text=home_icon.svg" alt="focus" />
  <img id="hamburger" src="//placehold.it/300x75?text=hamburger_icon.svg" alt="hamburger" />
</header>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: My apologies for not accepting the answer sooner, I didn't know that I was supposed to...still new at stackoverflow LOL. I think I sent you a message thanking you, if it didn't get through - Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: @Ingo Sure... Anytime... `:D` You sent message to where?